# Printing variable

Tags: python

So recently I want to make input thingy and I did this.

```
A = print('Hello world')

test = input()
if test == 'print Hello':
    print A
```

I want the input repeat to print "A" if the input is 'print Hello' can you help me?

Comment: Please explain in your own words what you think that `A = print('Hello world')` will do.

Comment: @tripleee If this is a proper [mre], then `print A` *do* indicate that the OP is using Python 2. As it is now, there's no way to actually know.

Comment: Lux, please take the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which looks like

```
variable = function()
```

will first evaluate `function()` (i.e. call the function) and then assign the return value from that function to the `variable`.

In other words,

```
A = print("Hello world")
```

will *immediately* print `Hello world` and then assign `None` to `A`, because that's what `print` returns. Perhaps you meant

```
A = "Hello world"

test = input("What do you want to do? ")
if test == 'print Hello':
    print(A)
```

Notice also the parentheses around the argument to `print`. In Python 3, you need the parentheses (and if you are using Python 2, you need to switch to Python 3 unless you *specifically* want to learn an obsolete version of the language which is [out of support since 2020](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)).

It is also possible, though less likely, that you wanted to assign a function to `A`, and then call that.

```
A = lambda: print("Hello world")

test = input("What do you want to do? ")
if test == 'print Hello':
    A()
```

where the `lambda:` basically creates an anonymous function, sort of like the code inside a `def` also will not be executed when you evaluate the `def`, only when you call the function it defined.